# NMinimize differential evolution: how do search points and initial points really work?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, implementation-details

I am puzzled by the settings of a specific method for `NMinimize` called `DifferentialEvolution`, given for example [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationGlobalNumerical.html). The settings include both `"SearchPoints"`, or the size of the population of evolving points, and `"InitialPoints"`, or the initial population(?). What I don't quite understand is that `"SearchPoints"` can be set to a value different from the number of specified `"InitialPoints"` and `NMinimize` will often happily proceed, and sometimes it won't.

What might be happening under the hood? If there are less `"InitialPoints"` than there are `"SearchPoints"`, will the population be filled up with random points to meet the specified number of `"SearchPoints"` before evolution begins or does it proceed with a population that is in fact smaller than `"SearchPoints"`? What about the opposite case?

Here is an example where we give much less `"InitialPoints"` than there are `"SearchPoints"`.

```
Clear[f, c, v, x1, x2, y1, y2, y3];
f = 2 x1 + 3 x2 + 3 y1/2 + 2 y2 - y3/2;
c = {x1^2 + y1 == 5/4, x2^(3/2) + 3 y2/2 == 3, x1 + y1 <= 8/5, 
   4 x2/3 + y2 <= 3, y3 <= y1 + y2, 0 <= x1 <= 10, 0 <= x2 <= 10, 
   0 <= y1 <= 1, 0 <= y2 <= 1, 
   0 <= y3 <= 1, {y1, y2, y3} \[Element] Integers};
v = {x1, x2, y1, y2, y3};

NMinimize[{f, c}, v, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]
(*{7.66718, {x1 -> 1.11803, x2 -> 1.31037, y1 -> 0, y2 -> 1, y3 -> 1}}*)

points = 5;
searchpoints = 50;
listpoints = {RandomReal[{0, 10}, points], 
RandomReal[{0, 10}, points], RandomReal[{0, 1}, points], 
RandomReal[{0, 1}, points], 
RandomReal[{0, 1}, points]}\[Transpose];

NMinimize[{f, c}, v, 
 Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution", "SearchPoints" -> searchpoints, 
"InitialPoints" -> listpoints}]
(*{7.66718, {x1 -> 1.11803, x2 -> 1.31037, y1 -> 0, y2 -> 1, y3 -> 1}}*)
```

If there are more `"InitialPoints"` than there are `"SearchPoints"`, `NMinimize` sometimes works and sometimes doesn't, depending on the value of the random seed for instance.